# The background of the parent does not transition (slide)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to have a transition effect when I hover a link. I want a text to smoothly appear after the link.

That is what I have so far:

```css
p {
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: chocolate;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    transition: width 1s;
}

p>span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}

p:hover>span {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="mailto:john.doe@server.com">@</a>
  <span>john.doe@server.com</div>
</p>
```

As you see, the text appears with a slide effect, but that does not work for the background of the parent. How can I make slide the background too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code. I'll list them down.

1. Closing `div` tag but I don't see any opening `div` tag.
2. You are setting a `width` on `p` and `span` both, but just one is required.
3. You are not turning the entire `mailto:` in a link, but just the `@` which I think is a bad UX. Not sure if this is by design.

I've modified your code a bit, so that it animates the background too, along with the email.

If you do not want the entire email as a URL, just move out the `span` and put it besides the `a` tag, rest should work as expected.

```css
p {
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: chocolate;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p:hover {
  max-width: 100%;
}

p span {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="mailto:john.doe@server.com">@<span>john.doe@server.com</span></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You cannot imagine the hours I try to make this work…

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios no offence, but you must be a backend dev xD I've seen many backend folks struggling to do the frontend stuff. glad it helped you out. Note that I am not animating your email anymore as I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: You guessed right, I've never tried to write a "real" site :P Your solution is perfect, this is exactly what I've tried to do.

Comment: Oh, just a small question: can I prevent the usage of a "magic" value for the initial "max-width" value?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios you'll need some initial value so that you can animate, ofcourse, I can try to hack it out if you want me to

Comment: but that will require some DOM change, if you are ok with that, I can provide another solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197118/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-mr-alien).